# application.yml is not copied when resource exclude is used

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am using the following build settings in my Spring Boot object:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/clientApp</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>node_modules/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The whole clientApp directory, containing a node.js application is properly copied, without the unwanted node_modules directory. As an unwanted side effect, the application.properties/.yml file is not copied anymore.

How do I only get the node_modules directory from getting copied and while application.yml keeps getting copied?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an `include` for `application.properties|yaml`

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/clientApp</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>node_modules/application.*</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>node_modules/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Alternatively you could consider moving `application.properties|yaml` from `src/main/resources/clientApp/node_modules` up to `src/main/resources/clientApp`.